# How to do sublist with angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, sublist

I'm looking for how to do submenu with angular:

> - 1
> - 2

is ok :

```
<mat-sidenav-container fxFlex>
  <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="case 1">
        <mat-nav-list>
          <mat-list-item *ngFor="let step of case 1" (click)="selectedStep = step">
            <mat-icon matListAvatar svgIcon="icons:{{step.icon}}" class="avatar"></mat-icon>
            <span>{{step.name}}</span>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-sidenav>
```

but

> - 1
>
>   - 1.1
>   - 1.2
> - 2
>
>   - 2.1
>   - 2.2
>   - 2.3

is not, how to do this second example?

Comment: Are you asking for how to make the second example?

Comment: yes, please, how to do this?

Comment: Here is an example of something similar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnkg3h-xppmzz?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.html . Let me know if this works for you. Otherwise you can try just using basic html to do this. https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists_nested

Comment: @canpan14 thanks a lot, it works :)

Comment: If you are ng material 6> then you can give their tree layout a shot https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Comment: Now please, how to print in .html my titles?
1 then 1.1 then some text
I tried with (click)="selectedStep = step" but I can't print both step and substep